# Nextjs state not updating on route change

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I know there's a lot of questions in the same topic. I've been reading for about 2 days about this and i cant make it work. So my situation is this:

I have several dynamic routes in my Nextjs app and each fo these routes have a table inside the content. I update the state of that table based on some filters i have setup which is working fine, but when a route changes, the state of the table is still keeping the previous state.
I have tried adding a key to the `Table` component like this: `key={router.asPath}` but its not making any difference.

I also added a key to `getStaticProps` like this:

```
return {
    props: {
      pageData,
      serverLocations,
      faq,
      key: data?.serverLocations?.data[0]?.attributes.Slug,
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
```

Now i'm trying to update the state on `router.events` but again, no joy!

Below is my code so you can see what i'm doing wrong:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, useTheme } from "@mui/material";
import PricingTable from "./PricingTable";
import FiltersDialog from "./PricingFilters";
import IconFilters from "./icons/IconFilters";
import Spacer from "./dynamicBlocks/Spacer";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function TableWithFilters({ theData }: any) {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [filtersDialogOpen, setFiltersDialogOpen] = useState(false);

  const Columns = Object.entries(theData[0]).map(([property, columnLabel]) => ({
    property,
    columnLabel,
  }));

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    data: theData,
    filters: Columns.slice(3, -2),
    columns: Columns,
    filterObj: Columns.slice(3, -2).reduce(
      (r: any, { property }: any) => ((r[property] = 0), r),
      {}
    ),
  });
  

  const onFilterApply = ({ target: { value, name } }: any) => {
    const newFilterObj = { ...state.filterObj, [name]: value };
    setState({
      ...state,
      filterObj: newFilterObj,
      data: theData.filter((props: any) =>
        Object.entries(newFilterObj).every(([key, val]: any) => {
          return props[key] >= val;
        })
      ),
    });
  };

  const onRouteChange = useCallback(() => {                              |
    setState({                                                           |
      ...state,                                                          |
      data: theData,                                                     |
      filterObj: Columns.slice(3, -2).reduce(                            |
        (r: any, { property }: any) => ((r[property] = 0), r),           |
        {}                                                               |
      ),                                                                 |
    });                                                                  | This is
  }, [setState]);                                                        | the code
                                                                         |I am trying
  useEffect(() => {                                                      |to use to 
    // subscribe                                                         |fix this
    router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", onRouteChange);              |
    // unsubscribe                                                       |
    return () => router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", onRouteChange);|
  }, [onRouteChange, router.asPath]);                                    |
                                                                         |
  console.log("STATEEE", state);
  console.log("DATAAA", theData);

  return (
    <>
      <FiltersDialog
        openFilters={filtersDialogOpen}
        closeFilters={() => setFiltersDialogOpen(false)}
        staticData={theData}
        filterData={state.filterObj}
        filterProperties={state.filters}
        onFilter={onFilterApply}
      />
      <Button
        onClick={() => setFiltersDialogOpen(!filtersDialogOpen)}
        startIcon={
          <IconFilters
            width='24'
            height='24'
            color={theme.palette.primary.main}
          />
        }
      >
        Open Filters
      </Button>
      <Spacer spacerHeight='40px' />
      <PricingTable
        key={router.asPath}
        tableData={state.data}
        tableColumns={state.columns}
        tableHeader={Columns}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you put `console.log('effect')` inside the `useEffect(()=>{}, [onRouteChange, router.asPath])`, the logging works well? If it works fine, can you just put `onRouteChange()` inside the useEffect? I wanna separate a problem first.

Comment: useEffect works but calling `onRouteChange()` inside is not making any difference.

Comment: I've answered based on your situation, please check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to [this](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#state-is-tied-to-a-position-in-the-tree). I'm guessing your component position does not change and react preserve its state, actually I can simulate your situation. So could you try following [those options](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#resetting-state-at-the-same-position)? I think option2 is easier to implement. You can check out just to put 'key' props with `Math.random()` whether it works ok or not. If it's ok, please replace `Math.random()` with your proper value.(As I mentioned, use Math.random() just to check this solution is ok.)

```
parent-component.jsx

export default ParentComponent(){
    return <TableWithFilters key={Math.random()} theData={...}>...</TableWithFilters>
}
```

Comment: If you check my code above (scroll to the bottom to the `<PricingTable />` component), i already tried adding a key `key={router.asPath}` where my router paths are all unique so no need for `Math.random()`.

Comment: @Ilir State belongs to the component where the state is declared. So key has to be placed like this `<TableWithFilters key={unique value}>...</TableWithFilters>. If `TableWithFilters` is top parent, please wrap it with other component and set key.

Comment: Ah just found a solution but yours works as well :) you were right, i added `key` on the wrong sopt. I will go with your solution because its cleaner. Check my answer also

Answer (score 0):

Anyone having similar issue. My mistake was that i shouldn't use `useCallback` in the `onRouteChange` function but it should be a plain function like this:

```
const onRouteChange = () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      data: theData,
    });
  };
```

However @iamippei's solution works as well but i placed the `key` in the wrong spot. So you can go with whichever solution. Both are working.

Comment: IMO using a random React key should be just about the last ditch effort sort of thing. Fixing the logic to do the right thing is always preferred.

Comment: I, as well,  think that using `Math.random()` to create keys is bad practice in terms of performance. However i have id's coming from my CMS which i can use for key props. You think that again my solution would be better than using a key?

Comment: Stable React keys are fine, random React keys are next to useless.